# XAMPP default folder on OSX

Tags: macos, xampp

Getting Started manual says I can put my files in /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/ folder and in /Sites/ folder, but when I put files in /Sites folder it gives me this error:

```
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
Wed Mar 17 11:29:01 2010
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Is there something that needs to be changed?

Also, when I try to restart XAMPP via Terminal I get this message:

```
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp: line 184: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles//var/proftpd/start.err: No such file or directory
fail.
Contents of "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles//var/proftpd/start.err":
cat: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles//var/proftpd/start.err: No such file or directory
```

Does this have something to do with the installation?

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved, unknown commands in .htaccess files.

Comment: I have the same exact problem. Would you mind elaborating on the solution you found, Ivan? It would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Yeah, as I said, there were some invalida command in my local .htaccess file so when I removed them, everything work as it should. Maybe you should check yours?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow these:

```
sudo mkdir /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/proftpd/

sudo touch /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/proftpd/start.err

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp fix_rights
```

Answer (score 2):

have you put a file which is either index.html or index.php

if no put a index.php file in htdocs with

```
 <?php
    $uri= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/site/');
    exit;
 ?>
```