# after XAMPP install on Mac Sierra - it works, but there is no XAMPP folder. Where is everything?

Tags: apache, xampp, macos-sierra

I have installed XAMPP.  It works.  I'm trying to figure out the following:

1/ it appears there are now TWO apache servers on my mac.  XAMPP just installed an additional server. One is already installed on the default Sierra OS. Is that correct?

2/ I can't find where XAMPP is reading files (document root). in the newly created directory: XAMPP.APP, the file structure is not as indicated in the FAQ's.  For example, there is no xamppfiles or logs directory in the XAMPP.app directory.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi before posting your question did you take a time to search here? I find the same Issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465655/xampp-default-folder-on-osx

Answer (score 1):

I installed XAMPP-VM (VM - as in virtual machine). Therefore, in the XAMPP application, I needed to click on "Volumes" and select "Mount" . I can then see this mounted volume in the MAC finder under "Shared".  From there, I  can get to all the necessary files including "lampp/htdocs".

Answer (score 0):

1. I haven't encountered a web server on the default installation of macOS.
2. Run XAMPP in the applications folder and then click on the 'Open Terminal' button. At the prompt, type `cd /opt/lampp` and this is the document root.

Comment: If  I "mount" the /opt/lampp volume from the XAMPP app, I can see it in the MAC finder.  I'll need to read up on "mounting volumes" to understand this better.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Also,I just realized I installed XAMPP-VM for MAC not just the XAMPP.