# XAMPP Mac PhpStorm PHP Interpreter

Tags: php, macos, xampp, phpstorm

I installed XAMPP on my mac and it works so far. However If I want to create a new project with PhpStorm I need to add an interpreter. I found out that it should be under `/Applications/XAMPP/xampp/...`

I don't have a XAMPP folder in Applications, similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413793/after-xampp-install-on-mac-sierra-it-works-but-there-is-no-xampp-folder-wher)

While this gives me access to `htdocs`, I can't find the PHP interpreter, where is it located?

Comment: Maybe it is because you are using xampp, for Mac there is MAMPP, for windows WAMPP, for linux there is LAMPP. But not sure, never used mac with xampp.

Comment: Should be somewhere in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/...`. Make some `test.php` file with `<?php phpinfo();` content and serve it with your Apache from XAMPP -- check what php.ini config files it uses -- such file should normally be next to PHP executable file. Other than that -- better check it with XAMPP Mac users, as usually MAMP is used on MacOS.

Comment: Using MAMPP resolved the issue. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Run `which php` in your terminal. The path that it returns is where your CLI interpreter is located. It should be `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php`.